# How to replace some text with URL in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I want to replace some text from the string with link. I dont know how can I display it. SO far below code displays string with href link.

```
<span class="text">{{ $t(myText) }}</span>

    myText() {
        var text = "You can click text.";

        var href = "<a href='https://www.google.com'>Click Here</a>";

        var replaced = text.replace("click", href);

        return replaced;
    },
```

Comment: When you're using the handlebars syntax, the content will be inserted as plain text. You might want to use `v-html` instead, i.e. `v-html="$t(myText)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment: [the handlebars/moustache syntax is used to insert plain text into your template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text). That means that any string that contains HTML will be inserted **as-is** without parsing it as DOM.

In order to insert HTML into your template, you will need to use the [`v-html` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html), i.e.:

```
<span class="text" v-html="$t(myText)"></span>
```

However, note that this presents a security risk if you're allowing users to insert their own content into the element.

Comment: How can i open in new tab ?

Comment: `target="_blank"`